# Sum SQL rows on every nth and group

Tags: sql, group-by, partition, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My data is as follows:

```
QUARTER_CMT   DEPT   SALES
7             A      39
8             A      23
9             A      33
10            A      45
11            A      50 
12            A      110
1             B      44
2             B      56
3             B      87
4             B      22
```

I am aiming at getting total `SALES` for every 4 quarters by `DEPT` and retain `Quarter_CNT` number as a rollup.

```
QUARTER_CMT   DEPT   SALES_TOT
7             A      140
11            A      160 
1             B      209
```

Work in progress code. I thought to sub-group totals and join to latest `QUARTER_CMT` to have one row by `DEPT` :

```
SELECT 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DEPTORDER BY QUARTER_CMT) as RN,
 QUARTER_CMT,
 DEPT,
--RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ODDZIAL ORDER BY QUARTER_COUNT) AS RowNumberRankOrg,
--NTILE(4) OVER(PARTITION BY ODDZIAL ORDER BY QUARTER_COUNT) AS RowNumberRank,
SALES

FROM TABLE_1
ORDER BY DEPT, QUARTER_CMT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to divide row_number to 5 for determine the periods

```
SELECT MIN (QUARTER_CMT) QUARTER_CMT, DEPT, SUM(SALES) SALES, PART
FROM (
    SELECT *, FLOOR(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DEPT ORDER BY QUARTER_CMT) / 5) AS PART
    FROM TABLE_1
) AS T
GROUP BY DEPT, PART
ORDER BY DEPT, PART
```

Result:

```
QUARTER_CMT DEPT SALES       PART
----------- ---- ----------- -----------
7           A    140         0
11          A    160         1
1           B    209         0
```

Comment: Can you please post what exact number division by 5 returns on your side? In Snowflake result of division looks odd to me.

Comment: I also added the quarter part to the result. maybe you also need an int conversion.

Comment: `PART` returns following: `0.200000, 0.400000, 0.600000, 0.800000, 1.000000, 1.200000` etc

Comment: it looks like needs to convert to int. i made an update for this.

Comment: I ran nested code and got results: `QUARTER_CMT(7), PART(0); QUARTER_CMT(8), PART(0); QUARTER_CMT(9), PART(1); QUARTER_CMT(10), PART(1); QUARTER_CMT(11), PART(1); QUARTER_CMT(12), PART(1)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
with a as (
  select 
    row_number() over(partition by dept order by quarter_cmt)-1 n, 
    quarter_cmt, dept, sales
  from t
  order by dept, quarter_cmt
) 
select min(quarter_cmt) quarter_cmt, dept, sum(sales) sales_tot
from a
group by dept, floor(n/4) 
order by dept, quarter_cmt
;
```

Assuming this sample data:

```
create or replace table t as
select $1 QUARTER_CMT, $2 DEPT, $3 SALES from values 
  (7,'A',39),
  (8,'A',23),
  (9,'A',33),
  (10,'A',45),
  (11,'A',50),
  (12,'A',110),
  (1,'B',44),
  (2,'B',56),
  (3,'B',87),
  (4,'B',22)
;
```